# Hibernate named query doesn't return all the result in select clause by using entity java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a java entity called Product in which I have a property having a manytoone relation and another property having the manytomany relation as well as other properties having native java types (String,Int,double)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT")
@NamedQueries(
@NamedQuery(
name="findProductByCategoryAndPictures"
query="Select distinct p from Product p inner join p.categories cat inner join p.picture pic  where p.id = :idProduct"
)
)
public class Product {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(...),@JoinColumn(...)})
    private Category categories ;
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="Picture",joinColumns={})
    private List<Picture> picture ;
    
    // Getters & Setters
}
```

I created a named query in which I retrieve my Product object with joins on my two properties manytoone and manytomany, but I can't get in the result of my object the values of my two other properties. I only get the values of my native properties

I have juste this result

```
{
 "id" :"1",
 "name" :"test",
 "price" :"10",
 "quantity" :"18",
}
```

but i want to have this result

```
{
 "id" :"1",
 "name" :"test",
 "price" :"10",
 "quantity" :"18",
 "categories" :"..." ,
 "picture" :[] ,
}
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is `@JsonIgnore`. It will mark a property or list of properties to be ignored. Remove `@JsonIgnore` over your fileds.